# PhotoSwipe | create Title Element | Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, css-position

i want to add an Title Element below my Image Gallery created with PhotoSwipe.
But my Title Element sticks not under the Image. It sticks to fast in the Image when Browser rescaling vertically.

JS to create the Element:

```
            lightbox.pswp.ui.registerElement({
                name: 'werkInformationen',
                className: 'smallWerkInformationen',
                appendTo: 'wrapper',
                onInit: (el, pswp) => {
                    var wrapDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    wrapDiv.className = 'wrapDiv';

                    var popUp = document.createElement('div');
                    popUp.className = 'popUpWerkInformationenTitle';
                    popUp.id = 'popUpWerkInformationenTitle';

                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.className = 'child';
                    span.id = 'popUpWerkInformationenTitleSpan';
                    
                    wrapDiv.appendChild(popUp);
                    popUp.appendChild(span);

                    el.appendChild(wrapDiv);

                    pswp.on('change', (a,) => {
                        var paramsFromCurrentWerk = new URLSearchParams(lightbox.pswp.currSlide["data"]["src"]);
                        document.getElementById("popUpWerkInformationenTitleSpan").innerHTML = paramsFromCurrentWerk.get('id') + " | " + paramsFromCurrentWerk.get('werkName') + " | " + paramsFromCurrentWerk.get('material') + " | " + paramsFromCurrentWerk.get('kuenstler');
                    });
                }
            });
```

Output to HTML:

```
<div class="smallWerkInformationen pswp__hide-on-close">
    <div class="wrapDiv">
        <div class="popUpWerkInformationenTitle">
            <span class="child">PLACEHOLDER TEXT</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapDiv {
    min-width: 600px;
}

.smallWerkInformationen {
    position: relative;
}

#popUpWerkInformationenTitle {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#popUpWerkInformationenTitleSpan {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Expected Result until there is no space:
[Expected Result until there is no space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApBEA.png)

My Result:
There is enough Space to fit the Text Element below but it goes in the Image.

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTJTC.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is already an Caption example.
But not that exactly what i want.

https://photoswipe.com/caption/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).